# How to add a controller variable to a database row in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to add a variable in the controller to a database row using activerecord and rails.

To do this now I have to add a hidden input tag to my view which contains the username of the member who is adding the row. This tag then gets picked up by my controller and added into the database.

Here is my hidden input field:

```
<% f.hidden_field(:uploader, value: @current_user.username) %>
```

And this is the code which creates the building

```
def create # (post) Add new records
    @bld = Building.new(params[:bld].permit(:name, :uploader, :description, :down_link))

    if @bld.save
      redirect_to my_buildings_url, :alert => 'Here\'s your new building!'
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

Is there any way to eliminate my hidden input tag and have the value of `@current_user.username` added to the database row in the controller (if you know what I mean)?

Comment: What's your authentication system? Where/how is `@current_user` set?

Comment: I have a custom one: 
`@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]`

That is in the application controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be done in the controller action as current user would be the person logged in. Therefore in your create action.

```
def create # (post) Add new records
    @bld = Building.new(params[:bld].permit(:name, :description, :down_link))
    @bld.uploader = current_user.username

    if @bld.save
      redirect_to my_buildings_url, :alert => 'Here\'s your new building!'
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

However you'd be better off defining an association called *uploader* which calls your user model. Then all you have to store is an integer. Also you don't open yourself to params trickery.